# Handle Browser Notification using Selenium using -Node.js

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am Automating some test cases using Selenium Webdriver and node.js,in chrome browser I make login to facebook and then I am getting browser level notification 'Show notifications with options Allow and Block'. I want to select Allow option. Can anyone know how to handle this kind of notifications using Selenium webdriver. please refer following snapshot for more details.
I saw few examples but none of them  work for node.js.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities({
         
        'args': ['--disable-notifications'],
        "args": ["--disable-plugins"],
        "chromeOptions": {
            "excludeSwitches": ["disable-popup-blocking"]
        }
    })
  
    .build();
```

Comment: You should merge the args keys. ['--disable-notifications', '--disable-plugins']